# when training sample increases accuracy decreases

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, keras-layer

I am testing keras's imdb dataset.  questions is, when I split to train and test for 2000 number of words I get close to 87% accuracy:

```
(X_train, train_labels), (X_test, test_labels) = imdb.load_data(num_words=2000)
```

but when I bump up the words to like 5000  or 10000, the model perform poorly:

```
(X_train, train_labels), (X_test, test_labels) = imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)
```

Here is my model:

```
model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', input_shape=(10000,)))

model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu' ))

model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
            loss='binary_crossentropy',
            metrics=['accuracy'])
history =model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=64,validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

Can any one explain why this is the case. I though with more sample (and less over fitting) I should get a very good model.

Thanks  for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing `num_words` doesn't increase the amount of samples but the vocabulary, leading to more words per sample (statistically), going in the direction of the [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality), which is harmful for the model.

From the [docs](https://keras.io/datasets/):

> num_words: integer or None. Top most frequent words to consider. Any less frequent word will appear as oov_char value in the sequence data.

Comment: Thanks Julian,  I was dissecting imdb data and I noticed that words has nothing to do with sampling size. Thanks for clarifying this .